# query modified documents and load other from cache in firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

To reduce the number of reads it is a general technique to maintain timestamp of last edits in documents and comparing timestamp to load only modified documents.
Here is an example from firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example):

```
db.collection('groups')
  .where('participants', 'array-contains', 'user123')
  .where('lastUpdated', '>', lastFetchTimestamp)
  .orderBy('lastUpdated', 'desc')
  .limit(25)
```

They claim this would reduce the reads.
I tried implementing the use-case, I have a document as shown below:
[image]

I have sections in my app where I use scorecards to list top scorers, My query is as follows

```
private void loadFriendScores(UserScorecard scorecard) {
        Query friendScoreQuery=scorecardRef.whereIn("uid", scorecard.getFriendsList())
                .whereGreaterThan("lastActive", scorecard.getLastActive()).limit(5);


        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserScorecard> friends = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions
                .Builder<UserScorecard>()
                .setQuery(friendScoreQuery, UserScorecard.class)
                .setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner())
                .build();
       
        TopScoresAdapter friendsAdapter = new TopScoresAdapter(friends, getContext(), this);
        binding.topScorersFriendsRcv.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);
        binding.topScorersFriendsRcv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }
```

I assumed the query to load all modified changes along with others (from cache):
The screen on android is as follows:
[image]

While I expected it to load all of my friendlist (as I understood from [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example)).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose they did not mention that we need to fetch the cached list, there is a way to do a cached request in firestore.
but I'm not sure if this is reliable perhaps the cache will be cleaned and the last request would be empty ,

then, you should save the last response using the localstorage library
@react-native-async-storage/async-storage

I'm struggling myself with the costs issue. The reads are way higher then 50 reads and I'm not sure how to count them properly. so I upvoted the issue